# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel throws exception: "Model could not be updated"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to update a simple model in MVC,but its not working,it throws an exception saying that the Model could not be updated:

```
      [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn([Bind(Exclude="TxtEmail")]Usuarios usuario,FormCollection fc)
        {
            try
            {
                UsuariosModel userModel = new UsuariosModel(usuario);
                userModel.Usuarios.TxtEmail = "test@test.com";

                UpdateModel(userModel);

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                 [...]
                }
                [...]
        }
```

This is the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="**O email é requerido")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$",ErrorMessage="**Email Inválido")]
public string TxtEmail
{
    get { return this.txt_email; }
    set { this.txt_email = value; }
}
```

How can i use this method "UpdateModel"?

Comment: Have you checked that the keys in the form collection match the properties in the model?

Comment: what are you doing with Usuarios usuario ?? it only has an email address and you are excluding it...?!? read my answer to fix it :)

Comment: no its has another properties,i just show email propertie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe your data does not match the validation.

I would try [TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470933.aspx).

> The TryUpdateModel method is like the UpdateModel method except that the TryUpdateModel method does not throw an InvalidOperationException exception if the updated model state is not valid.

Answer (score 10):

Look in your ModelState entries ( accessible with `this.ModelState` ).

ModelState contains an entry for each property and the errors for that property in the model you are trying to bind.  Chances are you are passing the wrong datatype along in the post or get action.

Comment: thk for your help.Ive figure out that UpdateModel takes values from FormCollection or from your Strong-Typed Model passed in as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
UpdateModel<UsuariosModel>(userModel);
```

I hope this will solve the problem.